# Android: How to use UriMatcher to switch multiple tables, query parametes and activities?

Tags: android, uri, multiple-tables, android-contentresolver

I would like to read your thoughts on how to solve the following problem. Here are the **basic requirements of the application** I am working on.

- Display multiple locations one city on a map.
- Support for **multiple** cities.
- Display the properties of a location on a separate details view.
- Location properties of each city **differ**.

I would like to implement a flexible **decision logic** that **switches between cities based on the location** that the map is at. That means, the initial information I rely on, is the map center. Here is the theoretical workflow.

1. Get the current center location from the map.
2. Translate the location into a city **url** and **uri**.
3. Download locations via HTTP using the url.
4. Store the locations in local database. One table for each city since location properties differ.
5. Load cached or downloaded data from a content resolver using the uri.
6. Create overlay items and include the **uri reference** and a **unique id**.
7. Open a details view when tapping on a location.
8. The details view should render the city specific location properties.
9. The location properties again are loaded via a content resolver based on the passed uri and unique id.

**Questions:**

1. I am particular interested on how you would switch cities, query parameters such as **column names** using the `UriMatcher` class.
2. Would you prepare **one** details view for each city? Or do you see any practical solution to **swap** text fields, label, .. based on the available property information?

---

To illustrate the different properties, here are two example cities and a content provider.

**Example:**

```
public class DatabaseParis {
    public static final class Contract {
        public static final String COLUMN_LATITUDE = "latitude";
        public static final String COLUMN_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    }
```

And another city ...

```
public class DatabaseDenver {
    public static final class Contract {
        public static final String COLUMN_LATITUDE = "lat";
        public static final String COLUMN_LONGITUDE = "lon";
        public static final String COLUMN_HEIGHT = "height";
        public static final String COLUMN_DIAMETER = "diameter";
    }
```

And a content provider ...

```
public class CustomContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
    public static final class Contract {
        public static final Uri URI_PARIS = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/cities/paris");
    }

    private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.cities.locations";
    private static final int URI_CODE_PARIS = 0;
    private static final UriMatcher URI_MATCHER = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    static {
        URI_MATCHER.addURI(AUTHORITY, "cities/paris", URI_CODE_PARIS);
    }
```

I am unsure about using **one** or **multiple content provider** since I read putting all database references into one can be a problem when the data should be synced in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one who deals with such a scenario should consume the following information sources.

- [Developing Android REST client applications, Virgil Dobjanschi, Google I/O San Francisco, 2010](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html)
- [ContentProvider and REST API, Benjamin Brombach, Android UserGroup Berlin, 2012](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4rncoVb9uFGaUlpUnlLSzdoZ1U/edit?pli=1)